# Application throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android

I created 3 Activities.

1. ElecBillActivity
2. AddBillActivity
3. ResultActivity

I successfully enterd into the second Activity using an Intent but as soon as I click the Submit button in the second Activity, I am getting an exception.

I tried many ways but I am unable to understand the problem.

This is my logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sai.android.billing/com.sai.android.billing.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(NativeMethod)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at com.sai.android.billing.ResultActivity.<init>(ResultActivity.java:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
E/AndroidRuntime(  506):        ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(   70):   Force finishing activity com.sai.android.billing/.ResultActivity
W/ActivityManager(   70):   Force finishing activity com.sai.android.billing/.AddBillActivity
W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4079d8f8 com.sai.android.billing/.ResultActivity}
I/ARMAssembler(   70): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x445b36e0:0x445b38a8] in 1634844 ns
I/Process (  506): Sending signal. PID: 506 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   70): Process com.sai.android.billing (pid 506) has died.
E/InputDispatcher(   70): channel '4060e840 com.sai.android.billing/com.sai.android.billing.ElecBillingActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(   70): channel '4060e840 com.sai.android.billing/com.sai.android.billing.ElecBillingActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/WindowManager(   70): WIN DEATH: Window{4060e840 com.sai.android.billing/com.sai.android.billing.ElecBillingActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(   70): WIN DEATH: Window{406f4868 com.sai.android.billing/com.sai.android.billing.AddBillActivity paused=true}
E/InputDispatcher(   70): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=151, events=0x8
W/InputManagerService(   70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 506 uid 10038
```

I am also providing the link for my [code](http://www.4shared.com/file/w9sPrKc8/ElectricityBilling.html).

As my problem seems to big and my class files are too big I provided the download link here.
As I am a new user I am unable to post the screenshots here.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code in the question. It should be around line 21 of your `ResultActivity` class judging by the LogCat output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the logs you got a `NullPointerException` in `ResultActivity.java` on line 21... taking a look into your source code, this is caused by calling `getIntent()` which is a member function of `Activity` which can only be called after the `Activity` is created. Therefore, move your initialization code into the `onCreate` method.

Change your member definitions to:

```
private TextView resultOk;
int highLimit,lowLimit,highRate,lowRate,defaultRate,amount;
Bundle bundle;
String userName;
String meterNumber;
String prevReading;
String currReading;
int pR;
int cR;
int units;
String u;
String a;
```

Further on you are calling `getIntent().getExtras()` and store it in the variable `bundle`. But as you never put any extras in your `Intent` in `AddBillActivity`, `bundle` will be `null` and when you try `bundle.getString(...)` it will throw another `NullPointerException`!

First change to make is to give an `android:id` attribute to your `RadioGroup` in the form.xml file. Set it to `radios` and add the this line to your member variables in `AddBillActivity`:

```
public static RadioGroup radios;
```

As well as this line to the `setUpViews` method:

```
radios = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radios);
```

Then change the `addTask` method in `AddBillActivity` to

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(AddBillActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
intent1.putExtra("bill_name", billNameEditText.getText().toString());
intent1.putExtra("bill_number", billNumEditText.getText().toString());
intent1.putExtra("bill_previous", billPrevEditText.getText().toString());
intent1.putExtra("bill_current", billCurrEditText.getText().toString());
intent1.putExtra("radio", radios.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
startActivity(intent1);
```

And now you can get all those extras in your `onCreate` method in `ResultActivity`:

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
userName = bundle.getString("bill_name");
meterNumber = bundle.getString("bill_number");
prevReading = bundle.getString("bill_previous");
currReading = bundle.getString("bill_current");
pR = Integer.parseInt(prevReading);
cR = Integer.parseInt(currReading);
units = pR - cR;
u = bundle.getString(String.valueOf(units));
a = bundle.getString(String.valueOf(units));
```

This should do it ;)

Comment: @Michael Rose Thank you for your reply.I applied the changes you have advised.But I am getting an other exception.My Logcat says 

`E/AndroidRuntime(  622): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  622):        at com.sai.android.billing.ResultActivity.onCrea
te(ResultActivity.java:38)`

I wrote that code using a tutorial as the reference,I will be very grateful to you if you can help me out!!

Comment: @Sai Ok, there we go... you call `getIntent().getExtras()` to get the `bundle` BUT you never put any extras in the intent! This should be done in your `AddBillActivity` before calling `startActivity(...)`. I will update my answer in a few minutes with the required changes!

Comment: @Michael Thanks a ton!! :)..its working now!!But I have a small problem.

`resultText.setText(getString(R.string.resultOk) + 
    "\n" + userName
    + "\n" + u + "\n" + a);`

The output screen is showing :

               *name*
                null
                null
I am not able to populate the values in the output screen,can you please check the code if I have written anything wrong??

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: @Michael Here is the screenshot for the output... [link](http://tinyurl.com/3kouu9e)

Comment: Ahm, yeah I oversaw this, it's the same mistake you made with the other bundle / extra calls. The procedure with Intent extras is that you first `putExtra`s in your Intent and then you get all extras by calling the `getExtras()` method on an intent. Afterwards you can get any extra from the bundle by calling `get<Type>(<key>)`, I strongly recommend reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). You just want to get the string value of `units`, so use `units.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable assistance..I understood the mistake and I made some changes to the code,its working good now,getting all right values.

The app is flawless now ;)

U ROCK :D :)